# what might be the reason , kafka consumer acknowledge, is throwing InterruptedException?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

this is code from KafkaMessageListenerContainer , at what contexts their is a possibility of InterruptedException , can be thrown by this code , suddenly in my app logs ,which is consuming the messages from topic and process , then acknowledge the messages , seeing below error messages

```
Interrupted while queuing ack for


@Override
            public void acknowledge() {
                try {
                    if (ListenerConsumer.this.autoCommit) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Manual acks are not allowed when auto commit is used");
                    }
                    ListenerConsumer.this.acks.put(this.record);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    **throw new KafkaException("Interrupted while queuing ack for " + this.record, e);**
                }
                if (this.immediate) {
                    ListenerConsumer.this.consumer.wakeup();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What version are you looking at; that code is no longer there (since 1.3 - current version is 2.1.4).

In any case, any interrupt of the thread (e.g. shutting down the task executor) will cause that problem.